# Is this code thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's say we have a thread-safe compare-and-swap function like
`long CAS(long * Dest ,long Val ,long Cmp)`
which compares `Dest` and `Cmp`, copies `Val` to `Dest` if comparison is succesful and returns the original value of Dest atomically.

So I would like to ask you if the code below is thread-safe.

```
while(true)
{
    long dummy = *DestVar;
    if(dummy == CAS(DestVar,Value,dummy) )
     {
        break;
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Dest and Val parameters are the pointers to variables that created on the heap.
InterlockedCompareExchange is an example to out CAS function.

Comment: Is this C# or C++?  Please pick one.

Comment: Of course it does. One is native, the other isn't. They have different promises on atomicity of different operations.

Comment: @Oded:  the whole point of the CAS is to ensure atomicity is accounted for.

Comment: besides, C++ has no promises of atomicity whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit. An edit to the question means most of this isn't relevant. Still, I'll leave this as all the concerns in the C# case also carry to the C++ case, but the C++ case brings many more concerns as stated, so it's not entirely irrelevant.

---

Yes, but...

Assuming you mean that this CAS is atomic (which is the case with C# `Interlocked.CompareExchange` and with some things available to use in some C++ libraries) the it's thread-safe in and of itself.

However `DestVar = Value` could be thread-safe in and of itself too (it will be in C#, whether it is in C++ or not is implementation dependent).

In C# a write to an integer is guaranteed to be atomic. As such, doing `DestVar = Value` will not fail due to something happening in another thread. It's "thread-safe".

In C++ there are no such guarantees, but there are on some processors (in fact, let's just drop C++ for now, there's enough complexity when it comes to the stronger guarantees of C#, and C++ has all of those complexities and more when it comes to these sort of issues).

Now, the use of atomic CAS operations in themselves will always be "thead-safe", but this is not where the complexity of thread safety comes in. It's the thread-safety of combinations of operations that is important.

In your code, at each loop either the value will be atomically over-written, or it won't. In the case where it won't it'll try again and keep going until it does. It could end up spinning for a while, but it will eventually work.

And in doing so it will have exactly the same effect as simple assignment - including the possibility of messing with what's happening in another thread and causing a serious thread-related bug.

Take a look, for comparison, with the answer at [Is this use of a static queue thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870713/is-this-use-of-a-static-queue-thread-safe/3871198#3871198) and the explanation of how it works. Note that in each case a CAS is either allowed to fail because its failure means another thread has done something "useful" or when it's checked for success more is done than just stopping the loop. It's combinations of CASs that each pay attention to the possible state caused by other operations that allow for lock-free wait-free code that is thread-safe.

And now we've done with that, note also that you couldn't port that directly to C++ (it depends on garbage collection to make some possible ABA scenarios of little consequence, with C++ there are situations where there could be memory leaks). It really does also matter which language you are talking about.

Comment: +1 for that long and explanatory answer. :) So with using `Interlocked.CompareExhange` the code is thread-safe in C#. But what are the concerns about C++ case even if we sure that CAS function is thread-safe?

Comment: I must have explained myself less well that I hoped. Using Interlocked.CompareExchange means that those 5 lines are threadsafe, but your program as a whole won't be. Indeed with C# they're equivalent to a simple assignment. It's meaningless to talk of single simple calls as threadsafe, you have to think about it in terms of larger sets of operations.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell, for any environment.  You do not define the following:

- What are the memory locations of `DestVar` and `Value`?  On the heap or on the stack?  If they are on the stack, then it is thread safe, as there is not another thread that can access that memory location.
- If `DestVar` and `Value` are on the heap, then are they reference types or value types (have copy by assignment semantics).  If the latter, then it is thread safe.
- Does `CAS` synchronize access to itself?  In other words, does it have some sort of mutual exclusion strucuture that has allows for only *one* call at a time?  If so, then it is thread-safe.
- If *any* of the conditions mentioned above are untrue, then it is *indeterminable* whether or not this is all thread safe.  With more information about the conditions mentioned above (as well as whether or not this is C++ or C#, **yes, it does matter**) an answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this code is kind of broken. Either you need to know how the compiler is reading `*DestVar` (before or after `CAS`), which has wildly different semantics, or you are trying to spin on `*DestVar` until some other thread changes it. It's certainly not the former, since that would be crazy. If it's the latter, then you should use your original code. As it stands, your revision is not thread safe, since it isn't safe at all.